# Is there a version of NHibernate Query Analyzer that works with NH3?

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a version of NHibernate Query Analyzer that works with NHibernate 3?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the official [code repository is now on github](https://github.com/ricardoborges/NHibernate-Query-Analyzer). As this is an open source project, you're always welcome to fork the repository, make the necessary changes to make it work with NH3, and send a pull request or patch to the current maintainer, Ricardo Borges.